# Polygon doesn't rotate correctly

Tags: java, libgdx, rotation, polygon

I'm making a game where I need to work out collisions for different characters. The problem is, when I try to rotate the character's polygon, the polygon starts moving all over the screen. When it's only at 0 degrees of rotation, it works fine, but anything else and it moves away from the character's position. Basically, is there a better way to rotate than by using `polygon.setRotation()` or am I just doing it wrong? Here's the code:

```
public Polygon getPoly() {
    Polygon poly = new Polygon(new float[] {
            position.x - (width / 2), position.y + (width / 2),
            position.x + (width / 2), position.y + (width / 2),
            position.x + (width / 2), position.y - (width / 2),
            position.x - (width / 2), position.y - (width / 2)
    });

    poly.setRotation(rotation);
    poly.translate(width / 2, width / 2);

    return new Polygon(poly.getTransformedVertices());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out, I have to do `poly.setOrigin(position.x, position.y)` to set the rotation relative to the character. The complete code is here, if anyone needs it:

```
public Polygon getPoly() {
    Polygon poly = new Polygon(new float[] {
            position.x - (width / 2), position.y + (width / 2),
            position.x + (width / 2), position.y + (width / 2),
            position.x + (width / 2), position.y - (width / 2),
            position.x - (width / 2), position.y - (width / 2)
    });

    poly.setOrigin(position.x, position.y);
    poly.setRotation(getRotation());
    poly.translate(width / 2, width / 2);

    return new Polygon(poly.getTransformedVertices());
}
```